# How to include large data set AzureWebRole

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

We're trying to setup a service in an azure webrole that requires a large dataset (approx 10GB over 35,000 files). 
What's the best approach to this?
We've tried:

i) Including all the files in the visual studio project as content files - VS grinds to a halt

ii) Putting the files into blob storage and downloading them as needed - service grinds to a halt, presumably because we've hit the IOPS limit on the instance by saving the files to disk. We don't want to use a large instance as we won't hit the IOPS level in normal running.

iii) Including a zip file and then extracting it at startup - again grinds to a halt.

I'm assumming that there's a way of including all files in the depolyment package without putting them in the VS project, but then we have to upload a 10GB deployment package everytime we update so that doesn't seem ideal.
The files need to be local on an SSD because of speed.
Does anybody have any good solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Putting 10 GB files in package is certainly not desirable + it is not even allowed as the maximum size of your package file can be 600 MB only.

One possible solution for your problem would be to make use of [`Azure File Service`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/05/12/introducing-microsoft-azure-file-service.aspx) which is built on SMB protocol. Though it is in preview, I think it would fit the bill perfectly. What you can do is upload the files there and then map the `File Service Share` where these files are located as a network drive in your VM (e.g. Z:). Then as and when you need the files, you can simply copy those files from this network drive to your local VM and work with those files.

Comment: Is there any difference between this and downloading the files from blob storage? You still fall foul of the large I/O at the start as you have to save them locally. It's annoying that you get a large disk with an Azure WebRole but no way to use it.

Comment: One difference that I see is the convenience. Since a File Service Share is mounted as a drive on the VM, you can simply use `System.IO` to perform file operations (like copy to local). With Blob Storage, you have to make use of Storage Client library and it would download the files over HTTP. One thing that is not clear to me is why do you need to download this 10GB data when your role starts. Can't you download the files when you need them?

Answer (score 0):

This really should be on ServerFault, as it's an infrastructure question, not a programming one. Plus it's opinion-soliciting, asking for the "best" approach to downloading content to your role instances. So the question runs the risk of being closed.

That said: The worker/web role instances don't necessarily have an IOPS limit (which is different from network bandwidth limits). Blob storage does have a per-blob limit of of 60MB/sec throughput and 2,000 transactions per second (those would be *storage* transactions), and 20,000 / sec across the entire storage account.

There is no *best* method of loading content onto a role instance. But let's just assume you're programmatically pulling blob content. You made no mention of *how* you are downloading content to your local instance, but the various Azure SDK implementations are capable of downloading via multiple parallel operations. Assuming you're using the .NET sdk, you can set `ParallelOperationThreadCount` on the `BlobRequestOptions` parameter, to some number greater than 1. (reference [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.blobrequestoptions.paralleloperationthreadcount.aspx)).